# How to prevent out-of-range datetime value error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

I am passing an ad-hoc Insert statement from c# application to the sql server 2000/2005.  Sometimes, if machine (where sql server is installed) datetime format is different than what I am passing in, it is throwing an error.

e.g. : In Insert statement I am passing '2010-03-10 00:00:00-05:00' this but machine regional date setting is different. I am getting this error:-

> The conversion of a char data type to
>   a datetime data type resulted in an
>   out-of-range datetime value.

Can I pass some generic date format in Insert statement from c# that works perfectly with any machine Regional Date Time settings.?

Answer (score 5):

"yyyymmdd" is safest, the basic ISO-8601 format. "yyyy-mm-dd" has issues as the link below mentions

With times: "yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss"

SQL Server can be slightly *odd* when dealing with datetimes. It's mostly fixed in SQL Server 2008 with the new date and time formats. **The** definitive article by [Tibor Karaszi](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp)

Edit: And another [article by Tony Rogerson](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/01/05/date-format-inconsistency-yyyy-mm-dd-or-yyyymmdd-when-2007-04-10-is-4th-october.aspx) for the unbelievers

Comment: date/times, just got to love them, now toss in JSON and ajax for some more fun :) +1 for the links

Answer (score 2):

Rather than building your SQL insert statement dynamically as strings, if you use either stored procedures or parameterised queries you will be able to pass the C# datetime value as a datetime object and there will be no format mismatch to cause problems.

[Correction - this only works on SQL 2008, see [gbn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420728/how-to-prevent-out-of-range-datetime-value-error/2420793#2420793) for a 2000/2005 valid string]
<strike>Alternatively, I believe that regardless of the SQL servers regional settings, if you pass your date time as a full [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string it will be handled correct.</strike>

E.g.

```
2010-03-10T14:17Z
```

Personally, I would recommend parameterised queries or stored procedures though as they solve lots of other problems too.

Comment: @gbn. Which bit, the parameters/stored procs or the ISO 8601 string?

Comment: Your ISO 8601 string. See my answer please about why the yyyy-mm-dd is SQL language setting dependent. Using stored procs/params is better because .net would handle the translation and SQL Server would get a native datetime value

Comment: @gbn. Really!? Crazy. I'll have to check that out.

Comment: @gbn, yeah thanks. I have. always good to try out this stuff though. Most of our database at work are 2000/2005 so I'm surprised I've not hit that before. I've removed the relevant bits from my answer.

Comment: it's not obvious, but if you use procs or parametrisation then SQL won't see the string and convert, because it's already datetime