# Dynamic versus explicit querys in sql-server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

Can anybody explain this?
Theoretically both are the same query but they give different answers.

a)

```
declare @date varchar(10)

set date = '03/02/2013'

select count(*) from table1 where (from <= @date) and (@date <= to)
```

b)

```
declare @date varchar(10)

set date = '03/02/2013'

set @sqlstring = 'select count(*) from table1 where (from <= ' + @date + ') and (' + @date + ' <= to)' 

exec sp_executeSql @sqlstring
```

The first set of sentences gives '2' as a result, and this is the correct answer, but in the second set of sentences, I have the same query executed dynamically through a string, but the answer is '0'.

Answer (score 0):

In the first, the effective SQL is

```
select count(*) from table1 where (from <= '03/02/2013') and ('03/02/2013' <= to)
```

In the second one, the effective SQL is

```
select count(*) from table1 where (from <= 03/02/2013) and (03/02/2013 <= to)
```

That is, the first one uses variables that do not require delimiters. In the second one, you have an expression of integer constants which has "[constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)" applied. Integer 3 divided by 2 divided by 2013 = 0 = 01 Jan 1900 when changed to a date

You'd need this:

```
set @sqlstring = 'select count(*) from table1
    where (from <= ''' + @date + ''') and (''' + @date + ''' <= to)'
```

Note that you should use `yyyymmdd` or ISO 8601 dates for consistency and clarity

- [How to prevent out-of-range datetime value error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420728/how-to-prevent-out-of-range-datetime-value-error/2420793#2420793)